# Elasticsearch recovery process settings

Tags: elasticsearch

Running ES 1.5.2

I'm testing recovery settings on 4 node cluster (32 cores, 30gb jvm heap, 5TB SSD per machine) with 1700 shards. The cluster is in a state of recovery and I updated the values as such:

```
   "transient": {
      "cluster": {
         "routing": {
            "allocation": {
               "disable_allocation": "false",
               "cluster_concurrent_rebalance": "8",
               "node_concurrent_recoveries": "8",
               "node_initial_primaries_recoveries": "16"
            }
         }
      },
      "indices": {
         "recovery": {
            "concurrent_streams": "9"
         }
      }
```

If a recovery is in process and the settings are updated will they take effect immediately or on the next possible recovery?

Currently I only see 8 primaries being initialized and only 2 nodes working. I.e: 30% network utilization and barely no cpu activity.

Comment: Is this physical hardware or virtualized environment?

Comment: Physical and 1 Gigabit network. Total index size is 1.5TB

Comment: Increase, also, `indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec` to `60mb`. And `disable_allocation` is not valid in 1.5. What do you mean by 'recovery'? You just started the cluster?

Comment: Ok let me try that! I had huge GC happen on 1 node which took almost 2 minutes so it got disconnected and it seems nodes couldn't detect master either. The cluster is yellow and shards are allocating... I have to look at the log files for errors. I called this a test because it's not a prod cluster so I figured i would try see if I can improve settings... So i know what to do in prod if needed.

Comment: Oh, then this is different. If you had a node disconnect, it's not good. Shards started to be moved around and you have quite a big cluster.

Comment: Btw the 60MB improved the speed a bit now I see 50% network usage. So is there other settings?

Comment: If your SSDs can take it, try to increase that setting to `80mb`. Nothing else, but keep in mind that `disable_allocation` is wrong. If you want to use it, it should actually be `cluster.routing.allocation.enable` with `all`, `primaries`, `new_primaries`, `none` possible values.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll check that too.